# How to add GitLab repository in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git, gitlab

How to add Git-Lab on Eclipse?

So that I can just push or fetch from GitLab.
I am a newbie in this, please give more explanation.

Answer (score 32):

## I Preparation

Make sure you have eGit in Eclipse:

1. Help -> Installation details
2. See that "Eclipse Git Team provider" is in the list.

If it is not installed, follow the indications in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24305176/1595451) from @VonC

Make sure you have the URL to the repository in GitLab. Something like `https://gitlab.com/<someusername>/<somerepository>` You get it from gitlab.com when you are at the overview page for the project:

- Menu (the hamburger icon ≡, 3 horizontal lines),-> projects, then click in the one you want to work with from eclipse. Now you are in the overview page. Right beneath the name of the project and its description there are a few buttons to allow you to perform some actions. One of those buttons is a selector for SSH/HTTPS protocols. For now, select HTTPS and copy the URL that follows it: that is the URL to the project.

## II Now clone the repository locally, using Eclipse eGit.

These steps have been tested in Eclipse Kepler and Eclipse Luna. Rumor has it that they are outdated and might not work as indicated. If you use a newer Eclipse, take care and post back the new steps :-)

1. Window -> Open Perspective -> Other
2. Search for "Git", select it, and click "OK"
3. Click the button with an arrow and the tool tip "Clone a Git repository and add the clone to this view"
4. In the "Source Git Repository" wizard:

   - URI: the URL from the repository in GitLab, like  `https://gitlab.com/<someusername>/<somerepository>`
   - eGit has filled in the host and repository path for you.
   - Leave the connection as it is (https and no port) and fill in the details for the authentication: user and password you use to log in GitLab.com.
   - If you tick the "Store in Secure Store," Eclipse will handle user/password for you from now on; I do it, but it is not advisable if you share Eclipse installation with someone else, or you do not trust your PC to hold your passwords.
   - Click next
5. Branch selection wizard.

   - If there are more than one branch in the repository, you may now choose which one you want to clone locally, the one with which you want to interact. You may also choose to clone all branches to have them available.
   - Once you are done, click Next
6. Local destination wizard.

   - You may now choose where you want to place your local Git repository. eGit defaults to a subdirectory under you user, unrelated to eclipse, it works well. If you do not like it, change to your liking.
   - As with other Git installations, it will name the GitLab.com repository as "origin". You may also change that if you really want.
   - In the projects box check the "Import all projects" and, if you work with "Working Sets", you may choose now in which one to place it.
   - Click Finish.

eGit now works for a bit and shows you the newly cloned repository in the view. You have a cloned repository with which you will be able to interact from Eclipse.

## III Now import the project into Eclipse.

1. File -> Import...
2. Git -> Projects from Git -> Next
3. Existing local repository -> Next
4. Select the newly cloned repository -> Next
5. Import using the New Project Wizard -> Finish
6. Choose the project type that is hosted in GitLab.com. In my case is "Java Project;" in other occasions it has been "Maven -> Maven Project". Then click Next
7. Name the project and change the settings you want. As destination, do not use the default location, but navigate to the location of the cloned repository (as used in step 6 in the previous section *cloning the repository*) -> Next
8. Verify that the import looks like you want it and click Finish.

You may now work within Eclipse and use the Team menus to sync and commit and push.

Comment: Seems more detailed than my answer. +1

Comment: Thanks. I recently had to do it myself -using your help, thanks- and, used to write how-to instructions, together with the _"I am a newbie in this, so I kinda need more explanation"_ remark, gave me the idea of copying the how-to here.

Comment: Great! That is the kind of contribution and feedback which makes me go back To Stack Overflow every day.

Comment: Step 3 in "Now clone the repository locally, using Eclipse eGit."  is outdated, and cannot be followed :)

Comment: Hi @ineedahero, I've tested the import steps in Eclipse Kepler and Luna. No problems whatsoever. I'll add a line indicating that the procedure was tested with those versions. If you are working with newer Eclipse, feel free to add your own response, edit-add the steps for that version, or even comment in those steps and I will add them. If you did not succeed, let me know which Eclipse is that and I might try it at home.

Comment: It has been suggested that you can find the Installation details going to Help -> About Eclipse, where you can find an "Installations Details" button. But, also in Eclipse Neon (version 4), the Help -> Installation Details is a more direct access to the information we need to check in that step.

Comment: Hi @ineedahero, I've tested the import steps in Eclipse Kepler, Luna and photon. No problems whatsoever. I'll add a line indicating that the procedure was tested with those versions. If you are working with a different Eclipse, feel free to add your own response, edit-add the steps for that version, or even comment in those steps and I will add them. If you did not succeed, let me know which Eclipse is that and I might try it at home. 
It is true that in Photon the button does not have the blue arrow --now it is green--, but the tool tip remains. I'll edit to reflect the change.

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way is to usean Eclipse with EGit (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/article.html)

See "[Compare Eclipse packages](https://eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php?release=juno)" (the [standard Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-standard-432/keplersr2#), for instance, has EGit)

This will allow you to add a remote repo url referring to your gitlab repo hosting server.
This isn't specific to gitlab though, and you could add remote repos referring to Github or Bitbucket.
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Working_with_remote_Repositories

[image: http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/3/35/Egit-0.9-clone-wizard-url-page.png]

Answer (score 2):

Install Egit in eclipse using Install new software from http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is a [Mylyn Gitlab Connector](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/mylyn-gitlab-connector) now.

I think I'll give it a try

Comment: I guess that would be more for integrating additional features from gitlab, such as time, task and resource management, perhaps documentation, wiki and bug tracker, rather than work with the actual git repositories in gitlab? Interesting either way.