# How to import a gitlab project to eclipse as a maven project?

Tags: eclipse, maven, gitlab

I want to import it to eclipse as a maven project .i want to know it from very first step? any sources?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add GitLab on Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304759/how-to-add-gitlab-on-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to import your GitLab "project" (meaning a repo cloned from a GitLab server) into your Eclipse workspace.

If it is a java project, then you can use a plugin like "[eclipse-to-maven](https://github.com/vashishthask/eclipse-to-maven)" to convert that project to maven:

- Converts `.classpath` files into `pom.xml`
- If required, prints the dependency graph of eclipse projects.
- Moves source folders according to Maven convention. So for instance Java sources go to `src/main/java` folder.
- Removes spaces in the names of the folders. So "`Calculator Component`" becomes "`CalculatorComponent`"

Other manual conversions are described in "[Convert Existing Eclipse Project to Maven Project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2449461/6309)".